# Leaflet map not showing despite following quick-start guide

Tags: javascript, html, css, leaflet

The problem I am having is that the map is not showing up at all, there is a blank spot where the map is meant to be. I have followed Leaflet's quick-start guide and I still have yet to determine why my map does not show.

Below is the code I have so far:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Title</title>

        <!-- Stylesheets -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" 
        integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A==" 
        crossorigin=""/>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">

    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="mapid">
        </div>

        <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"
        integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA=="
        crossorigin="">

            var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

            L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={accessToken}', {
                attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
                maxZoom: 18,
                id: 'mapbox.streets-v11',
                tileSize: 512,
                zoomOffset: -1,
                accessToken: 'pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw'
            }).addTo(mymap);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try giving height to map div

Comment: Where is the CSS? They specifically state that the map container must have a definitive/fixed size (width and height). The solution will depend on whether you expect your map to be static or resizable. If you want a resizable map, you'll need to add the `ResizeObserver` of JS ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver ) and do `invalidatesize()` method on the map once more.

Comment: I do have the height for the map in a seperate css file, though I may add the resize function as well so thank you for the reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You import the Leaflet JavaScript file and have your page code within the *same* HTML `<script>` tag. In such case, browsers are supposed to *ignore* (not execute) the content between the script tags, i.e. your page code is not executed.

Simply separate in 2 different script tag pairs:

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<script>
var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
// etc.
</script>
```